# How to block senders in Messages app on Mac OS X? How to mark as spam?

Tags: macos, messages, spam

Getting many junk texts during election season.

Messages come to both my iPhone and MacBook Pro (connected via my iCloud account).

I'm not seeing any way to mark messages as spam, nor to block senders.

Opening app prefs, and trying to copy–paste the number into the blocked list isn't taking either.

Able to set conversation as do-not-disturb. This disables notifications, but isn't really all I want.

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave the iOS version below,. as that actually works - but for OS X it's nowhere near as efficient.

Messages > Prefs > Accounts > Blocked
Click +
You can type the phone number but nothing will happen unless the number is already recognised as a Contact [which is frankly infuriating].

One workaround might be to make a Contact called "zzz spam" & keep adding bad actors to that contact, which may also immediately add them to the banlist anyway.

*tbh, I'd prefer a better answer than this, if anybody has one*

[Previous answer, mistakenly for iOS]
From [Apple KB : Block phone numbers and contacts or filter messages on your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch](https://support.apple.com/HT201229)

> **Messages**
>
> If you're in Messages, open the conversation, tap [image: info],
>   then tap the name or phone number. Scroll to the bottom of the Info
>   screen, then tap Block this Caller.

Comment: I'm asking about blocking text message senders in Messages app for Mac, not iOS.

Comment: ugh, sorry - possible but ridiculous... They must be a Contact to block them :/  Messages > Prefs > Blocked. Typing the number gets you nowhere... they must be already in contacts to make it work. I'll add it to the answer, but I hope someone finds something better.